# SharePoint 2010 XSLT treating calculated column number as string which breaks ddwrt:Max

Tags: 2010, xslt, data-view-web-part, ddwrt

I have a calculated column that is a number field. It basically adds to other number fields. When I look at the item through the website I see the format as "1,050" (with the comma).

In a DVWP using XSLT when I try to find the max value using 'ddwrt:Max(...)' it does not find the true max because it seems to be treating the values as strings where 900 is greater than 1000.

Here is a snippet of the `dsQueryResponse` and my XSLT.

The `dsQueryResponse`:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
    <Rows>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="125" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="225" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="325" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="425" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="525" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="625" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="725" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="825" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="925" ></Row>
        <Row nCcTileRightEdge="1,025" ></Row>
    </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

The XSLT in question:

```
<xsl:variable name="maxRightEdge" select="ddwrt:Max(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@nCcTileRightEdge)" />
```

And this is returning 925.

How can I get the true max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change your variable definition to convert the string to a number first:

```
<xsl:variable name="maxRightEdge" select="ddwrt:Max(number(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@nCcTileRightEdge))" />
```

Details: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number